# Automate html in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation

I'm currently preparing a cool video presentation on my html web page. At the end of it, I want to be able to click on the video and be taken to a page - however I only want the link to come into effect at a certain time.

I've done some research and I can't find anything about this.

As an example, let's say that I want to make a link on something...

```
<a href="#" id="automate">This link will go somewhere after 15 seconds</a>
```

How can I make it so that `<a>` tag doesn't work for 15 seconds with jQuery or JavaScript? (JavaScript preferred but it doesn't really matter!). Remember - I don't want that whole line of code to suddenly appear - prior to the link working that should just be text!

Thanks!

Comment: Is it 15 seconds after the page has loaded, or 15 seconds after some other event has occured, like user started the video and then 15 seconds later the link becomes active?

Comment: It's 15 seconds after the page has loaded, yeah. It's not possible to detect when the video has been played isn't it?

Comment: I believe that depends on the the video-player. Have no experience of the built-in HTML5 player, if that fires any events, but I believe that players like [Flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/) and similar fire events when a video has stopped playing. In that case, you could listen for that event, and display the link when the event is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here delay is set to 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds in call to setTimeout). Change it to 15000 to make it 15 seconds

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout(convertTextToLink, 3000);
});

function convertTextToLink() {
    $('#thanks').html('<a href="http://example.com">Thanks for watching. You may now proceed.</a>');
}
```

Html

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>here are your vids</p>
<div id="thanks">Thanks for watching</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the html there for me! Great answer thank you very much :)

Comment: Welcome :) Don't forget to accept the solution, if you like it

Comment: Sorry about taking so long to accept that - my internet went funny for a while. I know this is getting a bit away from the question, but do you know how I would additionally make that link go away again? (Eg - `SendBackToTimeout(convertTextToLink, forever);` ?? Thanks!

Comment: To sum that up: It waits 3 seconds, it displays for 3 seconds, and then it hides it again forever!!

Comment: @AdamMcArthur
You can use call to setTimeout() to make a delayed execution of any code. So, in you case, if you wish to delete the link entirely after showing it for three seconds:

`$(document).ready(function() {
   setTimeout("convertTextToLink(); setTimeout(deleteLinkForever, 3000);", 3000);
});

function convertTextToLink() {
    $('#thanks').html('<a href="http://example.com">Thanks for watching. You may now proceed.</a>');
}

function deleteLinkForever() {
    $('#thanks').html('');
}`

If you would like to show/hide something periodically, then of course there're better ways

Comment: Formatting was totally broken in the comment, but I hope you get the idea

Comment: That's fine. Thanks for that :). So you're saying there's better ways to show/hide something? My situation has changed now, and I need to create a slideshow that at specific times shows (by fading in) text, and then hides (by fading out) the text.

Answer (score 1):

```
var waiting = true;

//set waiting to false after 15 seconds
setTimeOut(function() { waiting = false },15000); 

$('#automate').click(function(e) {
    if(waiting === true) {
       e.preventDefault(); //prevent the link from firing
    }
});
```